# Facing issue in Mapper.py and Reducer.py when running code in Hadoop cluster

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Running this code to take Probability in Hadoop cluster my data in CSV File.

When I run this code in cluster getting this error "java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1" anyone fix my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""mapper.py"""
import sys

# Get input lines from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    line = line.strip()

    # Split it into tokens
    #tokens = line.split()

    #Get probability_mass values
    for probability_mass in line:
        print(str(probability_mass)+ '\t1')
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""reducer.py"""
import sys
from collections import defaultdict


counts = defaultdict(int)

# Get input from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    #Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    line = line.strip()

    # skip empty lines
    if not line:
        continue  

    # parse the input from mapper.py
    k,v = line.split('\t', 1)
    counts[v] += 1

total = sum(counts.values())
probability_mass = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
print(probability_mass)
```

```
marks
10
10
60
10
30
```

```
Expected output Probability of each number

{10: 0.6, 60: 0.2, 30: 0.2}

but result still show like this 
{1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1}
```

Answer (score 0):

The real error should be available **in the YARN UI**, but putting the probability as the key won't allow you to sum all the values at once because they all would end up in different reducers

If you have no key to group the values by, then you can use this, which should funnel all data to one reducer

`print('%s\t%s' % (None, probability_mass))`

Here is a working example for the output that you wanted, which I tested with just an input file, not in Hadoop

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

counts = defaultdict(int)

# Get input from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    #Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    line = line.strip()

    # skip empty lines
    if not line:
        continue  

    # parse the input from mapper.py
    k,v = line.split('\t', 1)
    counts[v] += 1

total = float(sum(counts.values()))
probability_mass = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
print(probability_mass)
```

#### Output

```
{'10': 0.6, '60': 0.2, '30': 0.2}
```

You can test your code without Hadoop with `cat file.txt | python mapper.py | sort -u | python reducer.py`

Plus, mrjob or pyspark are higher level languages that would provide more useful features

Comment: What about it? `ClassA` in the reducer will always be assigned to the last value of that mapper

Comment: it was my mistake. in the last it will be **print ('%s\t%s') % (probability_mass, Classprob[probability_mass])** in reducer

Comment: You can't have headers in mapreduce. You should include your example Dataset (top 20 rows) and expected output in the question

Comment: I have attached the data set and expected output.

Comment: Note: Your problem is not suited for mapreduce because you must know the total of all values ahead of time. Therefore, you must output `(None, ClassA)` from the mapper. And you've not posted the actual error, which comes from the YARN UI.

Comment: mapreduce job running successfully. but i can't get my expected output.

Comment: What output **are** you getting?

Comment: 10:1 10:1 10:1 10:1 10:1 10:1 10:1 10:1 like this.. its repeat the number..

Comment: 20:1 20:1  20:1  20:1  20:1  20:1  20:1 like same number repeating. i want count the same number and take probability with total number.

Comment: its working the redcuer code.. but now mapper code have a probelm..

Comment: Your input file has nothing to split, so why are you calling that? Also `marks` header needs removed from the file

Comment: Check my mapper update code. its working now and job done. but result still show like this {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1}

Comment: which issue occurs now ? do you understand. i try it different methods. but it can't. output like this {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1} {1:1}

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, your mapper needs to output `None\t{value}`. Because the reducer will group all values together by key

Comment: so it should be like this `print(str(probability_mass, None))` instead `print(str(probability_mass)+ '\t1')`

Comment: the Code is working on mapreduce. but output still like this. `{'1': 0, '0': 0, '3': 0, '2': 0, '5': 0, '4': 0, '7': 0, '6': 0, '9': 0}`

Comment: Do you understand where the issue still occurs ?