# Not getting my expected output in mapreduce using python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

Running this code to take Probability in Hadoop cluster my data in CSV File around 10k+.
I am using Google DataProc Cluster to run this code. kindly tell me how can I get my expected output. and the last thing maybe there is a logical issue or maybe some function issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""mapper.py"""
import sys

# Get input lines from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    # Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    line = line.strip()

    # Split it into tokens
    #tokens = line.split()

    #Get probability_mass values
    for probability_mass in line:
        print("None\t{}".format(probability_mass))
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
"""reducer.py"""
import sys
from collections import defaultdict


counts = defaultdict(int)

# Get input from stdin
for line in sys.stdin:
    #Remove spaces from beginning and end of the line
    line = line.strip()

    # skip empty lines
    if not line:
        continue  

    # parse the input from mapper.py
    k,v = line.split('\t', 1)
    counts[v] += 1

total = sum(counts.values())
probability_mass = {k:v/total for k,v in counts.items()}
print(probability_mass)
```

My CSV File look like this.

```
probability_mass
10
10
60
10
30
```

```
Expected output Probability of each number

{10: 0.6, 60: 0.2, 30: 0.2}

but result still show like this 
{1:0} {0:0} {3:0} {6:0} {1:0} {6:0}
```

I will save this command in nano and then run this.

```
yarn jar /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming.jar \
-D mapred.output.key.comparator.class=org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedComparator \
-D mapred.text.key.comparator.options=-n \
-files mapper.py,reducer.py \
-mapper "python mapper.py" \
-reducer "python reducer.py" \
-input /tmp/data.csv \
-output /tmp/output
```

Comment: By giving every map output the same key, you're guaranteeing that they all hit the same reducer, removing the point of MapReduce. You'd need a separate job beforehand to count the total number of records (or save yourself the hassle and use something like Spark).

Comment: @Ben Even Spark would force this operation to one executor

Comment: Please show how you're running this code and your input file

Comment: Please don't duplicate questions [Facing issue in Mapper.py and Reducer.py when running code in Hadoop cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59140021/facing-issue-in-mapper-py-and-reducer-py-when-running-code-in-hadoop-cluster)

Comment: @cricket_007 yes but they might find it easier to write in a way that doesn't make it do that.

Comment: @cricket_007 please check my update question where i show my command that how i run this in cluster.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you remove `-D mapred` properties? (which are deprecated anyway)

Comment: @cricket_007 how can i get the output graphical ? like i want use histogram.

Comment: Spark + Zeppelin or Hive + Hue/Superset should get most of the way there... MapReduce doesn't do graphical things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are splitting the line into individual characters, which would explain why you get 1, 3, 6, 0, etc as the map keys.

Don't loop, just print the line for the value; your mapper doesn't need to be more than this

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print("None\t{}".format(line.strip()))
```

Then, in the reducer, you're dividing an int by a larger int, which results in rounding down to the closest int, which is 0.

You can fix this by changing the dict to store floats

```
counts = defaultdict(float)
```

or make the sum a float

```
total = float(sum(counts.values()))
```

---

As mentioned before, this isn't a Hadoop problem, since you can test and debug it all locally

```
cat data.txt | python mapper.py | sort -n | python reducer.py
```

Comment: Thats fine now, I got the probability. but {1\n: 0.6245, 6\n: 0.2543, 3\n: 0.2345} what is this `\n` ?

Comment: It's a new line character that you're not stripping

Comment: only this {1\n: 0.6245, 6\n: 0.2543, 3\n: 0.2345}. i am expecting like this {10: 0.6245, 60: 0.2543, 30: 0.2345}

Comment: I know what you want. As I said, you're not stripping the newline somewhere between reading the file, getting lines, and putting keys into the dictionary. You could do `counts[int(v.strip())] += 1` for example, but there's already a strip before that, so it shouldn't be needed